# Install a single handle with latch on closet door

Tags: doors

I have a pantry door that has a dummy handle (a handle that looks like a normal door handle but is not connected to a latch).  The door stays closed using a fairly shoddy catch like this one [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0042YFBBS/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awd_l81HwbGC94ZJ9](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0042YFBBS)

I'd like the door to open and close like a normal door, but I don't want a handle on both sides of the door.  Besides cutting a spot for the latch on the door, and the strike plate on the frame, do I need to buy a special door handle system for this?  Or can I pull this off with a standard handle system somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you put a conventional door handle latch system on the pantry door you will want to have a working knob on the inside in the event someone gets shut inside the pantry!!

If the pantry is as you say a closet that no-one could get into then you certainly can install what is known as a "one sided door knob". Google it - you will find a plethora of ideas.

Comment: The "pantry" isn't really something you can walk into.  There's about an inch of space between the door and the shelves inside.  If you managed to get in there and someone closed the door, you'd have deeper problems than trying to figure out how to open the door ;) likewise I also have a similar "closet" where our HVAC is located, there's no way a person could get in there but the latching system on the door sucks